Angular Service return boolean from Observable
Big picture is I want the service to return a boolean as I don't want the consumer to have to do the subscribing/unsubscribing. I want them to call getBooleanFeatureToggle(toggleKey: string) and return the boolean.
  getBooleanFeatureToggleAsObservable(toggleKey: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return from(this.getBooleanFeatureToggleAsPromise(toggleKey));
  }

  public async getMyFlag(toggleKey: string): Promise<boolean> {
    let flag = false;
    const sub = await this.getBooleanFeatureToggleAsObservable(toggleKey).subscribe({

        next: (featureEnabled: boolean) => {
            console.log('featureEnabled', featureEnabled);
            flag = featureEnabled;
        },
        error: (error: any) => console.error(error)
    });

    return flag;
}

  public getBooleanFeatureToggle(toggleKey: string) {
    const myFlag = this.getMyFlag(toggleKey);
    console.log('myFlag', myFlag);
    return false;
  }


this is a bit confusing.

I have no doubt I've made it harder, obviously I need the observable to be done subscribing before sending the bool to the consumer.

Your getMyFlag return type is a promise, yet you return a boolean. Just create a void function that subscribes and in the subscription set a class member boolean value which you can read whenever. Although I do not see why you would have a problem with using it as observable as is. Maybe you can clarify that?

Just await the promise, why even bother with the observable since you do not want to subscribe to it!
 getBooleanFeatureToggleAsObservable(toggleKey: string): any {
    return this.getBooleanFeatureToggleAsPromise(toggleKey);
  }

  public async getMyFlag(toggleKey: string): boolean {
    const flag = await this.getBooleanFeatureToggleAsObservable(toggleKey);
    return flag;
}

  public getBooleanFeatureToggle(toggleKey: string) {
    const myFlag = this.getMyFlag(toggleKey);
    console.log('myFlag', myFlag);
    return false;
  }

